# Installing bootstrap sass with compass

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, sass, bundler

I'm trying to install bootstrap-sass and getting the error below. I've tried an older version of sass but bundler keeps installing 3.3.0.

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
sass (~> 3.2)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:inblock in '
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:inblock in '
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:inblock in '
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in fallback_load_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in'
from /usr/bin/compass:23:in load'
from /usr/bin/compass:23:in'
```

My Ruby Version - 
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

My Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gemspec

platform :rbx do
  gem 'rubysl', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'json', '>= 1.8.1'
  gem 'rubysl-test-unit', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'racc'
end
```

My Gemspec

```
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'bootstrap-sass/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name     = "bootstrap-sass"
  s.version  = Bootstrap::VERSION
  s.authors  = ["Thomas McDonald"]
  s.email    = 'tom@conceptcoding.co.uk'
  s.summary  = "Twitter's Bootstrap, converted to Sass and ready to drop into Rails or Compass"
  s.homepage = "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass"
  s.license  = 'MIT'

  s.add_development_dependency 'compass'
  s.add_development_dependency 'term-ansicolor'
  s.add_development_dependency 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
  s.add_runtime_dependency 'sass', '~> 3.3.0'

  s.add_development_dependency 'capybara'
  s.add_development_dependency 'poltergeist'
  s.add_development_dependency 'tzinfo'
  s.add_development_dependency 'jquery-rails'
  s.add_development_dependency 'slim-rails'
  s.add_development_dependency 'uglifier'

  s.files      = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
  s.test_files = `git ls-files -- test/*`.split("\n")
end
```

Comment: Compass 0.12 is not compatible with Sass 3.3.  You'll need to upgrade to an edge version (`gem install compass --pre`).

Comment: Hi Thanks for that, yeah I've read about this somewhere else and that said to downgrade sass which I also tried. Both to no avail.

Comment: What is your ruby version, and what's in your Gemfile and/or gemspec?

Comment: Added that info for you @ggPeti

Comment: Wait, so you're not just trying to install bootstrap-sass, but you have its source checked out and trying to run bundle install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you actually have the bootstrap-sass code checked out, change this line in the .gemspec:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency 'sass', '~> 3.3.0'
```

to

```
s.add_runtime_dependency 'sass', '~> 3.2.0'
```

After this, run `bundle update sass`, then `bundle clean --force`. The problem when downgrading the sass gem is that compass still tries to load the newer one, that's why you need the clean (or you could do a `gem uninstall` if it suits you better).

Answer (score 5):

Install the gem

```
gem install bootstrap-sass
```

If you have an existing Compass project:

```
# config.rb:
require 'bootstrap-sass'

bundle exec compass install bootstrap
```

If you are creating a new Compass project, you can generate it with bootstrap-sass support:

```
bundle exec compass create my-new-project -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap
```

This will create a new Compass project with the following files in it:

- _variables.scss - all of bootstrap variables (override them here).
- styles.scss - main project SCSS file, import variables and bootstrap.

Some bootstrap-sass mixins may conflict with the Compass ones. If this happens, change the import order so that Compass mixins are loaded later.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [yeoman(bower/grunt)](http://yeoman.io/index.html) to manage your client side libraries. Not only will it download bootstrap with comapss and install it, it will make it easy to update and automatically recompile sass when a file is changed and reload the browser using life reload. It comes with grunt which you can setup to minify js,css and compress svg, png etc.